# как задать сокет для подключения к компу

Tags: java

серверная программа запущена на компе, который подключен к компу через роутер. Пробовал так

```
InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("fortey-pc/192.168.10.1");
        this.socket = new Socket("91.105.184.152",8089,ipAddress,8089);
```

и так

```
this.socket = new Socket("91.105.184.152",8089,ipAddress,8089);
```

Если запускаю на одном компе через локалхост - работает

Comment: IP-адрес белый, порт расшарен?

Comment: IP-адрес белый, а как порт расшарить?

Comment: на роуторе хотя бы DMZ укажите на IP адрес компьютера.